# Bootstrap collapse does not toggle collapsing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Somehow bootstrap does not toggle the `collapsing` class to activate the transition and the element to `collapse in` without **any** transition. My code is like this:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class=" col-lg-12 collapse" id="collapse-me">
   <p> some text </p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-me" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-me">Collapse this</a>
</div>
```

When I test this in jsFiddle it works as expected but not on my site. My real question how can I debug this? Where can I find the listener which toggles `collapsing` class to make sure it is added and removed?

Comment: can you show your jsFiddle?

Comment: Can you show us your page so we can figure it out? It's hard for us to find the problem if on jsFiddle is working as expected.

Comment: My page is pretty big with numerous stylesheets and I highly doubt anyone would want to go through thousands of lines. Is there anyway to see if bootstrap's event listener is firing and toggling classes correctly?

Comment: jsFiddle is pretty much that part of the code with bootstrap libraries: http://jsfiddle.net/q8D56/36/

Comment: If it works in JSFiddle then you should find out the other thing which effect it. Or Post live link here

Comment: I'm running on localhost and don't have a live version yet

Comment: Are you sure you have included the bootstrap Javascript correctly?

Comment: Yes bootstrap `js` is loaded

Comment: Just solved it, I even tried using `grep` to find listener but somehow didn't. Some genius added `$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });` to disable navbar animation (I'm not the only one working on this) . To find bugs like this use chrome Dom listeners. This one was under show. How hard is to stay specific and do `$('.navbar .collapse')` for real.